# Transmission fell out of gear and now won't start

Tags: toyota, transmission, corolla

I was on the freeway when my gear was pushed into neutral. So I felt my car losing power so I stopped at a red light pressed the brake then put my car back into drive drove into a store parking lot and turned off my car. After turning it off it did not want to start anymore the engine did not rev or anything and the lights and power work its just the engine that doesn't start. It's a Toyota corolla 2006.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an automatic or manual transmission?

Comment: Details are needed.  As it is the question makes little sense to me.